# App behavior changes when going from iOS 13.6.1 to iOS 14

Tags: ios13, ios14

I just finished my app that I built for iOS 13.6.1 and everything was working as expected. I tried it on my girlfriend’s phone that is running iOS 14.0. A lot of the behavior has changed. Without going into details of what changed, I am just wondering if this a feature of iOS updates or a bug. I am new to iOS. Do developers have to rewrite their apps with major OS releases?

Answer (score 0):

Developers have to test their apps with new OS releases.

Here's a tip: You always specify the SDK used by the app and the lowest iOS version supported. If you don't change which SDK you use (like you continue using the iOS 13.4 SDK, just an example) then it is quite likely that your behaviour doesn't change, but if you switch to the iOS 14.0 SDK, the behaviour is more likely to change.